# Navigation to anotherview when accessoryButtonTapped in table view

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view in which I am using accessory button when it is tapped I want to navigate to other view controller. I have done this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    DateViewController *objDateViewController = [[DateViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DateViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objDateViewController animated:YES];

}
```

but its not working. Please help.

Comment: try do it at - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

Comment: i tried this also still not working

Comment: did you have any error return when tapped ?

Comment: self.navigationController??? is it really present?

Answer (score 2):

TRy this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ...

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    ...
    cell.accessoryView = button;

    return cell;
}


- (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether your delegate method is fired ?
2. You have your `viewcontroller` (where table view resides) in `navigationcontroller`

Comment: when i add tabel view in navigation view it does not show any thing blank screen comes

Comment: Is your viewcontroller in Navigation stack?

`DateViewController *objDateViewController = [[DateViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DateViewController" bundle:nil];

NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController)

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objDateViewController animated:YES];`

Comment: try to print ur navigation controller. If its not nil your viewcontroller is in navigation stack

Comment: Is your delegate method gets fired?

Comment: ya delegate mathod get fired

Comment: Is navigation nil? Or has any object in it?